# ¿Es correcto el uso del punto y coma como reemplazo a la coma luego de un inciso?

Tags: puntuación

Partiendo de la oracion

> El autor propone que una nueva organizacion economica es capaz de crear puestos de trabajo mejor calificados y remunerados, permitiendo asi un sendero estable de crecimiento a largo plazo.

agrego dos incisos

> El autor propone que—en lugar de insistir por los subsidios cruzados, los cuales llevaran a nuevas frustraciones—una nueva organizacion economica, abierta al flujo de capitales y apoyada en una economia mas diversificada, es capaz de crear puestos de trabajo mejor calificados y remunerados, permitiendo asi un sendero estable de crecimiento a largo plazo.

Estos incisos hacen que la coma se repita 3 veces, introduciendo ambiguedad sobre cual es el inciso. ¿Seria correcto reemplazar la ultima coma por un punto y coma?

> El autor propone que—en lugar de insistir por los subsidios cruzados, los cuales llevaran a nuevas frustraciones—una nueva organizacion economica, abierta al flujo de capitales y apoyada en una economia mas diversificada, es capaz de crear puestos de trabajo mejor calificados y remunerados; permitiendo asi un sendero estable de crecimiento a largo plazo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que hay exceso de comas inútiles para la compresión de la frase. Para mi lo correcto es:

> El autor propone que, en lugar de insistir por los subsidios cruzados los cuales llevarán a nuevas frustraciones, una nueva organización económica abierta al flujo de capitales y apoyada en una economía mas diversificada, es capaz de crear puestos de trabajo mejor calificados y remunerados, permitiendo así un sendero estable de crecimiento a largo plazo.

Aunque haría limpieza de preposiciones y artículos en toda la frase, veo más problemático la repetición de la palabra "nueva/s" y mezcla de tiempos verbales que las comas:

> El autor propone que en lugar de insistir por subsidios cruzados que provoquen nuevas frustraciones, una renovada organización económica abierta al flujo de capitales y apoyada en una economía mas diversificada, es capaz de crear puestos de trabajo mejor calificados y remunerados, permitiendo así un sendero estable de crecimiento a largo plazo.

Comment: En tu ejemplo, la coma que hay entre "diversificada" y "es" separa directamente el sujeto del predicado. Esto no es correcto según [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/entre-sujeto-y-verbo-no-hay-coma/)

Comment: También me dejé el acento de "más" 